# Excess inner html of all elements with a class using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to fetch a html field from all the elements returned by `find_elements_by_class_name` method. I fetched all the elements with a given class-name from a webpage using the above method and stored the list in a variable, like:

```
rows = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.order-row')
```

Now i am trying to iterate on `rows` list and print a `strong` field's inner html. Like:

```
for row in rows:
    print row.find_element_by_xpath('//td[3]/a/strong').get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

but every time it prints the value from first row for all the rows.

This is the xpath of the element from first data row of table where tr[4] is the first row with data:

```
//*[@id="myo-table"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]/a/strong
```

Expected output:

```
value 1
value 2
value 3
value 4
....
```

Current Output :

```
value 1
value 1
value 1
value 1
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath is asking to find the strong element in the entire DOM, and the method will always return the first one it comes across, thus the repeated 1.  Try using an XPath that is relative to the row element:

```
'.//td[3]/a/strong'
```